# How to create a new variable in sas?

Tags: variables, sas

I want to create a new variable which is equal to the column sum of an existing variable.the code i am using is-

```
data west;
input total;
set yash123;

total=sum monthly_sales;
proc print data=west;
var total;
run;
```

but its not working.

Comment: Maybe you can show some example about what data you have and how your desired output should look like.

Comment: `total=sum monthly_sales;` this line is not correct SAS syntax and will generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `proc summary` is all you appear to need :

```
proc summary data=yash123 nway ;
  var monthly_sales ;
  output out=west (drop=_:) sum(monthly_sales)=total ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a running total you can use:`total+monthly_sales;retain total;`

otherwise you can use `sum(monthly_sales) as total` in `proc sql` to have the total repeat for each observation.